# log4net use a different xml config file when in DEBUG mode compared to RELEASE mode

Tags: c#, xml, log4net-configuration

I have a webapp that I would like to use a different log4net config file when running under DEBUG mode compared to running under RELEASE mode.

I am using log4net version 2.0.3.

In my AssemblyInfo.cs class I have this code:

```
#if DEBUG
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "log4netDebug.xml",     Watch = true)]
#else
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "log4netLive.xml", Watch = true)]
#endif
```

In my Global.asax.cs class I have this code:

```
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(); 
log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(GlobalApp));
```

(log is a public static member of GlobalApp.)
In my log4netDebug.xml file I have this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Configuration for logging using log4net-->
<configuration>
<configSections>
<section name="log4net"  type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
</configSections>
<log4net>
<!-- Show logging in the Visual Studio output window-->
<appender name="TraceAppender"
      type="log4net.Appender.TraceAppender" >
<layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
   <conversionPattern value="%-6level - %message%newline" />
</layout>
</appender>
<appender
        name="AdoNetAppender"
        type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
    <threshold>INFO</threshold>
    <bufferSize
    value="1" />
    <connectionType
    value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data,  Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
<connectionString value="data source=BLAH;initial  catalog=BLAH;integrated security=True;persist security info=True" />
<commandText value="INSERT INTO Logs ([Date],[Thread],[Source],[Level],  [Logger],[Message],[Exception],[HostName]) VALUES (@log_date, @thread, 'LOG SOURCE',@log_level, @logger, @message, @exception, @hostname)" />
    <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@log_date" />
        <dbType value="DateTime" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout" />
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@thread" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="255" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%thread" />
        </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@hostname" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="255" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%property{log4net:HostName}" />
        </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@log_level" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="50" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%level" />
        </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@logger" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="255" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%logger" />
        </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@message" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="-1" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%message" />
        </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@exception" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="-1" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.ExceptionLayout" />
    </parameter>
</appender>
<root>
    <level value="ALL" />
    <!-- Show logging in the Visual Studio output window-->
    <appender-ref ref="TraceAppender" />
    <appender-ref ref="AdoNetAppender" />
</root>
</log4net>
</configuration>
```

I have tested this config script and it works if I place it in my web.config file.
The log4netDebug.xml file has the Copy always property set.

When I try to do something like this:
    System.IO.FileInfo fi = new System.IO.FileInfo("Log4NetDebug.xml");
    log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch(fi);

This doesn't work either.
I have read several stackoverflow and other web pages that describe how to do this and I seem to be doing what they recommend doing but it still deson't seem to work.

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [Constructor for the FileInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.fileinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) class, you will see that it expects *The fully qualified name of the new file, or the relative file name.*.

So when you do this `System.IO.FileInfo fi = new System.IO.FileInfo("Log4NetDebug.xml");` you need to specify the full path to the file.

As this is in a web app, you probably want something like this:

```
var logFile = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(HttpRuntime.BinDirectory, "Log4NetDebug.xml"));
```